# UITableView Stucks on setting attributed text (HTML) to UILabel Swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, nsattributedstring

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? CustomTableViewCell
    cell!.lblVerseNo.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"
    cell!.lblDescription.attributedText = self.tableViewArr.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? NSAttributedString
    return cell!
}
```

The tableViewArr contains HTML attributed string like below

```
if let htmlData = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding) {
       do {
            let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: htmlData, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
            tableViewArr.addObject(attributedString)
          } catch let e as NSError {
                print("Couldn't translate \(str): \(e.localizedDescription) ")
          }
}
```

This is what I do.....
But, while scrolling the tableview it's stucking in real device. It works perfectly in Simulator..

Thanks in advance.......

Comment: Are you getting any error while converting HTML attributed string?

Comment: No, I'm not getting any error. The attributed text works perfectly. But, When scrolling the tableview, it's not scrolling smoothly...

Comment: HTML parsing when creating an NSAttributedString is computationally quite expensive. Unfortunately you cannot dispatch this work to the background (see https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring/1524613-initwithdata)

Comment: I'm not parsing inside cellForRowAtIndexPath. I'm parsing html to NSAttributedString and construct the array in viewDidLoad and loading the array in tableview.....